# Metamask is not popping up to connect accounts

Tags: metamask, frontend

Hey i'm using Html/Javascript to connect the Metamask. I use "ethereum.request({method: "eth_requestAccounts"})" to connect the Metamask accounts. It get me connected to my metamask account at first when i ran it first time in the browser.

But when i disconnect the account and tried to reconnect using the same connect button the metamask doesn't popup for connecting the accounts. I also did refresh and tries to connect it again with the same connect button but nothing happens.

This is my code:

```
async function connect(){
    if (typeof window.ethereum !== "undefined"){
        await ethereum.request({method: "eth_requestAccounts"})
        document.getElementById("connectButton").innerHTML = "Connected!"
    } else {
        document.getElementById("connectButton").innerHTML = "Please install the Metamask"
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to connect to your MetaMask accounts multiple times, you can use the `ethereum.enable()` method instead of the `eth_requestAccounts` method.

Like that:

```
async function connect(){
    if (typeof window.ethereum !== "undefined"){
        try {
            await ethereum.enable();
            document.getElementById("connectButton").innerHTML = "Connected!";
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            document.getElementById("connectButton").innerHTML = "Error connecting to MetaMask";
        }
    } else {
        document.getElementById("connectButton").innerHTML = "Please install the MetaMask";
    }
}
```